# Java : Boxing and using ==

Tags: java, casting, referenceequals

Lets say i have something like

```
 int a = 100;
 int b = 100;
 Integer c = (Integer) a;
 Integer d = (Integer) b;
```

`c == d` results to true. Does that mean objects c and d point to the same Object in memory?

Can any one shed light here?

Do we create 2 objects c and d here? Are they different objects or same? `==` tells me that they are same objects.

I also read somewhere that casting doesn't create new objects. It's just a way of representing the same object. That makes sense if I am trying to cast lets say an Object to a Integer.

But what about this case, where there is no object in picture before (all we had is primitives) and we are trying to create Object `c` and `d` here?

Comment: Should be noted that you should avoid boxed values as much as possible. Collections are about the only place in the wild that makes sense to have boxed values.

Comment: @Qix: Nullable values is the other useful case (and for those, there is now a new option in Optional --- which of course is also a boxed value).

Comment: @thilo there are a select few cases where you need to null a primitive value. Point is, *really* ask yourself if what you're doing is being clever or if a nullable primitive value is *really* the proper solution. I can think of only one scenario where it's okay, and that's deserializable classes.

Answer (score 0):

Autoboxing works without casting. The reason you're seeing reference equality is because autoboxing internally calls [`Integer.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf(int)) which caches certain values:

> This method will always cache values in the range -128 to 127, inclusive, and may cache other values outside of this range.

Comment: But that's not something you should rely on, really. Don't use `==` to compare objects, even when it sometimes works.

Comment: @Thilo I don't see any problem with relying on a feature that's explicitly documented. It may be a bit counterintuitive, but I guess it depends how it's used.

Comment: It's not like this "feature" buys you anything. `equals` works much more reliably and does not form "bad habits".